# Error when using lightning:FileUpload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I can getting a weird error after uploading a file using the lightning:fileUpload component. After a file is uploaded a "Sorry to interrupt" prompt pops up with the error

> [Cannot read property 'validity' of null]
>   B.get validity()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop-input.js:2:14774
>   B.showHelpMessageIfInvalid()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop-input.js:2:15446
>   interactingState.onleave()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/interop-input.js:2:16524
>   c.forEach()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-utils-private.js:2:899
>   a.EventEmitter.emit()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-utils-private.js:2:878
>   a.InteractingState.leave()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-input-utils.js:2:2219
>   eval()@https://force-ability-204-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-input-utils.js:2:345

It seems like it is an internal error. Has anyone run into this or know how to fix it?

Component

```
<div role="dialog" id="TDModal"
        class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">

    <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <header class="slds-modal__header" style="margin-top: 6pc;">
                    <button style="font-size: 20px;top: 0.5rem;right: 0.5rem;color : black;"
                            class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
                            title="Close" onclick="{!c.hideDoc}">X</button>
            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Uploaded Documents</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium"
                style="padding: 0;height: 70%;">
            <div class="detail" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.uploadedDocs}" var="cus" indexVar="key">
                    {!cus.name} &nbsp; <lightning:button variant="base" label="X" value="{!cus.documentId}" onclick="{!c.delete}"/><br/>
                </aura:iteration>
                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                    <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach Documents"
                        name="fileUploader"
                        multiple="true"
                        recordId="{!v.lineWrapper.line.Id}"
                        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showFileUpload}">
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" id="overlay"></div>
    <aura:set attribute="else">&nbsp;</aura:set>
</aura:if>
```

JS Controller

```
handleUploadFinished: function (component, event) {
    // Get the list of uploaded files
    var uploadedDocs = component.get('v.uploadedDocs');
    var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");

    for (var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
       uploadedDocs.push(uploadedFiles[i]);
    }

    component.set("v.uploadedDocs", uploadedDocs);

    var fileWrapper = component.get('v.fileWrapper');
    fileWrapper.hasFile = true;
    component.set("v.fileWrapper", fileWrapper);
    component.set('v.showFileUpload', false);
    component.set('v.showFileUpload', true);
}
```

Comment: After a lot of testing I have found that the problem seems to be when the modal is closed. The modal is shown or hidden depending on the field showFileUpload.